# Visa type for an internship in UK

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa

I am a student and I have an unpaid four-month internship in the United Kingdom. My parents will support me during my stay. I don't have a certificate of sponsorship, I only have the contract.

I tried applying for Tier 5 Temporary Worker-Government Authorised exchange but the certificate of sponsorship is necessary for that type of visa. So can I apply for a standard visitor visa?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Tier 5 visa to be an intern in the UK (assuming you're not allowed to work in the UK under another right such as being an EU citizen).

If the company offering the internship cannot arrange a certificate of sponsorship then they need to do their research to understand the law and their obligations regarding international internships. There are organisations which can help employers do this.

You cannot use your contract to make the application and you cannot be an intern on a visitor visa.